Pydantic Field constraint does not trigger with Optional type
I have a class with some attributes I want to constrain to a range.
I did this with pydantics' Field constraint (e.g. ge=0), and expected the constraint to be enforced.
However, validation does not trigger as expected, and an invalid value is set. Here is a small working example:
from typing import Annotated, Optional, List
from pydantic import  Field, BaseModel, ValidationError
import pytest

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    # My implementation that fails. The Field constraint does not work as expected.
    f1: Optional[Annotated[float | List[float], Field(ge=0)]] = None
    # Modified to work. 
    f2: Annotated[float | List[float], Field(ge=0)] = None
    # To demonstrate that the inner type is not the root cause of failing check. 
    f3: Optional[Annotated[float,Field(ge=0)]] = None

def test_valid_input():
    # Valid input, passes as expected. 
    myclass = MyClass(f1=1, f2=1)
    assert myclass.f1 == myclass.f2 == 1
    ### THIS PASSES ###

def test_invalid_input_successful_validation():
    # Valid f1, invalid f2 --> raises ValidationError as expected. 
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        myclass = MyClass(f1=1,f2=-1)
    ### THIS PASSES ###
        
def test_invalid_input_failing_validation():
    # Valid f2, invalid f1 --> Expect to raise ValidationError, but it lets the invalid value through. 
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        myclass = MyClass(f1=-1,f2=1)
    ### THIS FAILS ###
    ### myclass.f1 == -1 ###     

Expected a ValidationError to be thrown at the invalid f1=-1, but instead, the value was accepted.
The tests above demonstrate this and also that Optional might be the culprit.
I am using:

python==3.11.2
pytest==7.2.0
pydantic==1.10.2


What version of Python are you using? With Python 3.13rc1, your code seems to work as written. First, all the tests pass:
$ pytest -v test_models.py
========================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.5, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0 -- /home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
collected 3 items

models.py::test_valid_input PASSED                                                                                                                                 [ 33%]
models.py::test_invalid_input_successful_validation PASSED                                                                                                         [ 66%]
models.py::test_invalid_input_failing_validation PASSED                                                                                                            [100%]

=========================================================================== 3 passed in 0.07s ============================================================================

And we can manually demonstrate the expected behavior:
$ python -i test_models.py
>>> x = MyClass(f1=-1,f2=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 212, in __init__
    validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyClass
f1
  Input should be greater than or equal to 0 [type=greater_than_equal, input_value=-1, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/greater_than_equal
>>> x = MyClass(f1=1,f2=-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 212, in __init__
    validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyClass
f2
  Input should be greater than or equal to 0 [type=greater_than_equal, input_value=-1, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/greater_than_equal

There is however a problem with your code; you can't apply the ge=0 validation to List[float]; that gets you:
>>> x = MyClass(f1=[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_validators.py", line 265, in validator
    if not predicate(x, constraint_value):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_validators.py", line 278, in <lambda>
    'ge': create_constraint_validator('ge', lambda x, ge: x >= ge, 'greater_than_equal'),
                                                          ^^^^^^^
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 212, in __init__
    validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_validators.py", line 270, in validator
    raise TypeError(f"Unable to apply constraint '{constraint_id}' to supplied value {x}")
TypeError: Unable to apply constraint 'ge' to supplied value [1.0]

If you want to support both lists and single values, consider this instead:
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

positiveFloat = Annotated[float, Field(ge=0)]


class OtherClass(BaseModel):
    f1: positiveFloat | list[positiveFloat] | None = None
    f2: positiveFloat | list[positiveFloat] | None = None
    f3: positiveFloat | None = None


Here we're creating an Annotated floating point type so that our fields can either be a single positiveFloat value or a list of postiveFloat values; that gets us what we want:
>>> OtherClass(f1=[-1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 212, in __init__
    validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for OtherClass
f1.constrained-float
  Input should be a valid number [type=float_type, input_value=[-1], input_type=list]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/float_type
f1.list[constrained-float].0
  Input should be greater than or equal to 0 [type=greater_than_equal, input_value=-1, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/greater_than_equal
>>>
>>> OtherClass(f1=[1])
OtherClass(f1=[1.0], f2=None, f3=None)

Note also that I'm saving some clutter here by using native types (list, etc) rather than imports from typing (List, Optional). This should work with any reasonably modern Python (which I think in this case means "anything >= 3.9").


Unfortunately the issue still remains, and MyClass(f1=-1) and MyClass(f1=[-1]) passes.

We already demonstrated that OtherClass(f1=[-1]) generates a ValidationError as expected. For completeness:
>>> OtherClass(f1=-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 212, in __init__
    validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for OtherClass
f1.constrained-float
  Input should be greater than or equal to 0 [type=greater_than_equal, input_value=-1, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/greater_than_equal
f1.list[constrained-float]
  Input should be a valid list [type=list_type, input_value=-1, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/list_type

With the above code, all three of these tests pass:
def test_valid_input():
    myclass = OtherClass(f1=1, f2=1)
    assert myclass.f1 == myclass.f2 == 1


def test_invalid_f2():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        OtherClass(f1=1, f2=-1)


def test_invalid_f1():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        OtherClass(f1=-1, f2=1)

These tests pass on Python 3.13rc1, 3.12.6, 3.11.9, and 3.10.15.
You can find the above code along with a more extensive series of tests in this repository.

Good catch on the python version and the type inconsistency!
I run on python==3.11.2, just to confirm here is my output:
`Python 3.11.2 (main, May  2 2024, 11:59:08) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.



from test_pydantic_field import MyClass
myclass = MyClass(f1=-1)
myclass = MyClass(f1=[-1])
`
and when I try with python==3.12.6 I get the same errors you do.



I additionally tried out your code with positiveFloat. Unfortunately the issue still remains, and MyClass(f1=-1) and MyClass(f1=[-1]) passes.

I don't believe that's correct. See the update to my question, which includes tests that pass on Python versions between 3.10 and 3.13rc1.
